# Remove scheduled date from all tasks matching a filter

Tags: taskwarrior

I have several tasks with the tags `event` and `lecture` which have a `scheduled` date I would like to remove.

Is there a way to do something like the following:

```sh
$ task +event +lecture annotate scheduled:never
```

without resorting to this monstrosity:

```sh
$ yes "/Scheduled
d
wq
" | task $(task +event +lecture status:pending uuids) edit rc.editor:ex
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
task +event +lecture mod scheduled:
```